# Storing null value in session variable

Tags: php, session, php4

I have two `PHP` files, in which i'd like to store a `session` variable `id` like this

```
if(authentification($login,$mdp) == 0)
                {?>
                <script>alert('logging failed');</script>
                <?php
                header('Location: Contacts.php'); 
                }
                else{
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
                $_SESSION['mdp'] = $mdp;
                $a = authentification($login,$mdp);;
                $_SESSION['id'] = $a;
                 header('Location: space.php'); 

                }
```

And in the file `space.php`

```
session_start(); 
$list = Get_companies_by_user($_SESSION['id']);
```

in the `function.php`

```
function authentification($login,$mdp){

                parametrs();    

                $Log_query=mysql_query(
                    "   
                        SELECT user_id 
                        FROM  reg_users
                        WHERE username ='$login'
                        AND   password   ='$mdp'

                        ") or die(mysql_error());

                        if ($Log_query == true && mysql_num_rows($Log_query) >0) {

                          while ($Res_user = mysql_fetch_array($Log_query) ) {
                        return $Res_user;

                        }
                        }
                        else return 0;

}
```

The problem is in the value of the variable `$_SESSION['id']` : why it is null in `space.php`? How can i fix this error?

Comment: Well, since `$a` is un-initialized variable, `$_SESSION['id']` will always be NULL.

Comment: Where is the authentification() function??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
function authentification($login,$mdp){
    $Log_query = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM  reg_users WHERE username ='$login' AND   password   ='$mdp'") or die(mysql_error());

    //The user should be unique, not more than 0
    if($Log_query && mysql_num_rows($Log_query) === 1){
        while ($Res_user = mysql_fetch_array($Log_query) ) {
            $user = $Res_user['user_id'];
        }
        return $user;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

You should also escape `$login` and `$mdp` with:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($var);
```

Comment: Try to echo `$a` on the first script you posted and watch what it contains

Comment: the value of `$a` is 6

Comment: So the function authentification works... There is something else outside what you posted... If `$a = 6` then `$_SESSION['id']` is also `= 6`... If you post `$_SESSION['id'] on `space.php` it is `0`? Or the function `Get_companies_by_user` returns nothing?

Comment: i change the code to `session_start();
require("function.php");
$a = $_SESSION['id'];

$list = Get_companies_by_user($a);` and it works!!!

Comment: Yes, obviously you need to include the file which contains the function to call it. Please accept my answer if it helped you